# What are valid characters and how to escape in clap.rs arguments?

Tags: rust, clap

I want to pass in some shape or form a dictionary/map/object into my clap app. I can preprocess the dict to turn it into some csv or whatever. My problem is that I cannot find in clap docs which characters are valid for the argument values and how to escape them. Is this unrelated to clap and instead shell specific?

Can I pass something like

`myApp --dicty="a=1,b=3,qwe=yxc"`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this unrelated to clap and instead shell specific?

Mostly, yes. `clap` is going to get whatever arguments the shell has determined and will parse that.

*However* clap has built-in support for value sets, from the readme:

> - Supports multiple values (i.e. `-o <val1> -o <val2>` or `-o <val1> <val2>`)
> - Supports delimited values (i.e. `-o=val1,val2,val3`, can also change the delimiter)

If that's not sufficient, then you'll have to define `dicty` as a `String`, you will receive the string `a=1,b=3,qwe=yxc` (I don't think you'll receive the quotes) then you'll have to parse that yourself, either by hand (regex/split/...) or with something more advanced (e.g. the csv crate though that's likely overkill).

That seems like a somewhat odd option value though.

FWIW structopt (which builds upon clap to provide a more declarative UI, and should be part of Clap 3) doesn't exactly have support for that sort of things but can be coerced into it relatively easily: https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/blob/master/examples/keyvalue.rs

With some modifications would allow something like

```
myApp -D a=1 -D b=3 -D que=yxc
```

or (though see comments in linked snippet for limitations)

```
myApp -D a=1 b=3 que=yxc
```

to be collected as a `vec![("a", "1"), ("b", "3"), ("que", "yxc")]` from which creating a hashmap is trivial.